# Isekai manga in which the main character lives alone as a child in the jungle and is loved by the gods

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for this manga where the main character lives alone as a child in the jungle and is loved by the gods who watch over him. Then he saves the lives of some important people. Later he develops slimes for different purposes.

Comment: This is a nice description but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) to see if there is anything else you could [edit] in? For example, when did you read this?

Comment: So, given the isekai manga involve characters from another world, and this is a child in the jungle, was he transported as a child? Transformed upon arrival?

Comment: ^_^ All together now! Three of us found the same answer in short succession.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is *[Kamitachi ni Hirowareta Otoko](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100195977)*, or "The Man Picked Up by the Gods".

[image: Cover of "The Man Picked Up by the Gods"]

> Ryoma Takebayashi, a 39-year-old salaryman with a hidden past, finds himself in a different realm. The gods tell him that he has died and they are sending his soul to their own world to replenish its magic source. Ryoma begins a new life reincarnated as an orphan boy, able to survive alone in the forest for 3 years. Blessed with convenient magic powers from the gods, Ryoma is finally living as his true earnest self, freed from his mundane and undermined past.

Indeed, he does farm slimes, as you can see in the image. More details are available in the reviews [here](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=122702), albeit in somewhat broken English.

Answer found with a search for *isekai manga boy jungle slimes*

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3):

*Kamitachi ni Hirowareta Otoko* (*The Man Picked Up by the Gods*) (2017) most likely.

From [isekaiscan](https://isekaiscan.com/manga/kamitachi-ni-hirowareta-otoko/):

> Ryouma Takuma, an overworked 39-year-old man finds himself in a strange white room. **The gods tell him that he has died and they are sending his soul to a different world, a world where magic exists.** Carrying over his experiences from his past life and new abilities given to him, **Ryouma awakens anew as a boy and is dropped in a forest where he discovers his affinity for taming monsters and in particular, slimes!** Together with his slime friends our protagonist faces living in a different world, learning more about his abilities and that there’s more than meets the eye when it comes to slimes.

---

Remembered from [Isekai manga with a person who is reincarnated after dying by a sneeze-induced concussion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212227), which also mentioned the "saving people" part:

> until one day he helps the party of the Duke who had come to visit the forest

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might be "[The Man Picked up by the Gods](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/the-man-picked-up-by-the-gods/)"

the quote on [mangarock](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-100195977)

> Ryoma Takebayashi, a 39-year-old salaryman with a hidden past, finds
>   himself in a different realm. The gods tell him that he has died and
>   they are sending his soul to their own world to replenish its magic
>   source. Ryoma begins a new life reincarnated as an orphan boy, able to
>   survive alone in the forest for 3 years. Blessed with convenient magic
>   powers from the gods, Ryoma is finally living as his true earnest
>   self, freed from his mundane and undermined past.

Additionally, vol 1, Chapter 3 is called "the secret of slimes", and has as its first quote: "using a slime as a mirror?  You can do anything, once you have a slime."

Answer (score -2):

[*My Gift LVL 9999 Unlimited Gacha*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/136930/Shinjiteita_Nakama-tachi_ni_Dungeon_Okuchi_de_Korosarekaketa_ga_Gift_Mugen_Gacha_de_Level_9999_no_Nakama-tachi_wo_Te_ni_Irete_Moto_Party_Member_to_Sekai_ni_Fukushuu___Zamaa_Shimasu):

> Legion (the Race Union), is a party with various race members gathered to dispel such discrimination. But, they have a hidden purpose behind it. They were ordered by countries other than human races to search for "Master," and take it under their own country. Raito, a human boy, was welcomed into the Legion because of his gift "Infinite Gacha," a gift that might be owned by "Master." But in the end, their investigation showed that Raito is not "Master."
>
> Raito was about to be killed by the Race Union members, but accidentally he steps on a "Transfer Trap." As a result, he was teleported to the lowest level of the dungeon and escaped from Race Union's members. In the deepest dungeon, he was attacked by a mythical demon of LV1000. In a desperate situation, Raito hits the "Infinite Gacha" repeatedly. Luckily, he draws the SUR card "Mei the Seeker Maid" level 9999. She helps Raito to repel the demons and saves his life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this manga and explain how it matches the question?

Comment: No slimes, no jungle, as far as I can tell.