# Isekai manga where the main protagonist has a pet giant slime and also befriends a suit of armor with a spirit by beating them

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I recall one moment from the manga where the main protagonist with his companions defeated some bandits, and then proceeded to pose as said bandits to a hero's party to train them(?).

This is basically the standout moment from it I can remember.

Comment: Could you consider taking a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide and help to add some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the manga you are looking for is [Kuro no Shoukanshi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112121/Kuro_no_Shoukanshi) (Black Summoner).

At the beginning he makes a pact with a slime, making it his familiar.  Soon after it evolves into a giant slime.  They then defeat an armored man who was cursed years before as a dungeon boss. He then joins with them and is then shown a few times as merely a spirit before regaining a body, which is then shown to be an empty suit of armor.  After that, they go to a city which has bandits underneath it that have been causing problems.  Upon defeating the bandits, the hero's party finds them. The MC then challenges the 4 hero's to a 4v1 match, after which they find out the MC is not the bandit leader and exclaim that he must have done this to train them.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

*Kamitachi ni Hirowareta Otoko* (*The Man Picked Up by the Gods*) (2017) came up as an answer to [Isekai manga in which the main character lives alone as a child in the jungle and is loved by the gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/219981/) recently, and seems like a match:

- hero has pet slimes
- hero saves a Duke's party

From *isekaiscan*:

> Ryouma Takuma, an overworked 39-year-old man finds himself in a strange white room. **The gods tell him that he has died and they are sending his soul to a different world, a world where magic exists.** Carrying over his experiences from his past life and new abilities given to him, **Ryouma awakens anew as a boy and is dropped in a forest where he discovers his affinity for taming monsters and in particular, slimes!** Together with his slime friends our protagonist faces living in a different world, learning more about his abilities and that there’s more than meets the eye when it comes to slimes.

There's a giant slime as well:

[image: big sticky slime]

Comment: if this is it, then there is at least one other manga mixed in with the description.  There doesn't seem to be any bandit fight, let alone posing as the bandits to train a hero's party.  Nor does there seem to be any possessed armor, or even a golem.

Comment: @shufly duly noted, will get back to searching when I have more time, then