# A manga about the main character trying to gain enough MP to summon a goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character wakes up with amnesia, not remembering who he is. He's surprised when a goddess starts speaking to him.

Apparently, he had fallen in love with her, and in exchange for being able to gather enough MP and the ability for her to become his familiar, the main character asked the Goddess to reset his class, ultimately resetting his levels and his memory as well.

He goes on an adventure to be able to fulfill summoning her and on the way tames a slime and a high level boss, which is a suit of armour. If I correctly remember his past, he was a soldier of sorts who was trying to protect a child which can be seen being eaten by bugs due to the fact that her body was rotting. In grief, he became a demon, or something like that.

I don't think it's an isekai since the main character himself wasn't transported into the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Kuro no Shoukanshi](https://myanimelist.net/manga/112121/Kuro_no_Shoukanshi)* or *Black Summoner* (2018) was recently provided as an answer to [Isekai manga where the main protagonist has a pet giant slime and also befriends a suit of armor with a spirit by beating them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/220197/) and fits this one as well.

> After winning an unknown raffle, summoner “Kelvin” woke up in an RPG-like world of magic and swords with all of his memories from his previous world erased. Joined by his invisible god-like guide, Melfina, Kelvin now journeys out into his new world to level up, build a party, and be the most powerful summoner!
>
> <sub><sup>Description from Mangakakalot</sup></sub>

Here's Kevin waking up to the goddess explaining he asked her to be his familiar, and traded memories from points:

[image: Kevin discovers Melfina]